Expressing $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{n^{2}}\right)$ as an elementary function
How do you express the infinite product: $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x}{n^{2}}\right)$$ as an elementary function?

What are the zeros of your function? BTW you might have missed $x$ in front of the product

the zeros are all the square numbers and im thinking it has something to do with the infinite product for the sinc function but idk how to continue on from there

Letting $x=\frac{y^2}{\pi^2}$ and then check Euler's product formula for sine. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler_Formula_for_Sine_Function/Real_Numbers

So you get $$\frac{\sin(\pi\sqrt x)}{\pi\sqrt x}$$

thanks for your help :)

Interesting is also the partial product.
$$P(p)=\prod_{n=1}^{p}\left(1-\frac{x}{n^{2}}\right)=\prod_{n=1}^{p}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt x}{n}\right)\prod_{n=1}^{p}\left(1+\frac{\sqrt x}{n}\right)$$
Using Pochhammer symbols
$$P(p)=\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)_p}{p!}\times \frac{\left(1+\sqrt{x}\right)_p}{p!}$$
$$P(p)=\frac{\Gamma
   \left(p-\sqrt{x}+1\right)}{\Gamma
   (p+1) \Gamma \left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)}\times\frac{\Gamma
   \left(p+\sqrt{x}+1\right)}{\Gamma
   (p+1) \Gamma \left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)}$$ Take logarithms, use Stirling approximation and re-exponentiate
$$P(p)=\frac{\sin \left(\pi \sqrt{x}\right)}{\pi  \sqrt{x}}\Big( 1+\frac{x}{p}+\frac{(x-1) x}{2p^2}+\frac{(x-1)^2 x}{6   p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)\Big)$$
